# Can get data from node, but not command line using postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I created a table called alpha and a table within alpha named 'event'. I can add a row to the event table, and retrieve all rows from the event table in node. However when I try in the command line I am getting a 'blank' when I select all.

**Command line (not seeing any rows):**

```
(master U:1 ✗) happy psql alpha
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

alpha=# psql \dt
          List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  |   Owner    
--------+-------+-------+------------
 public | event | table | pgOwner
(1 row)

alpha-# select * from event
alpha-#
```

**Node code (shows rows):**

```
let promise = require('bluebird');
let moment = require('moment');

let options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};

let pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
let connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/alpha';
let db = pgp(connectionString);

// add query functions
function getAllEvents(req, res, next) {
  db.any('select * from event')
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved ALL events'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}

function addEvent(req, res, next) {
  // let date = moment(new Date()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A');
  db.none('insert into event(firstName, lastName, eventDate, emotion, answer)' +
      'values(${firstName}, ${lastName}, ${emotion}, ${emotion}, ${answer})',
    req.body)
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Inserted one event'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}


module.exports = {
  getAllEvents: getAllEvents,
  addEvent: addEvent,
};
```

[image]

Comment: You need to end the statement with `;` in `psql`: `select * from event;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name works! can you write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4)

> At the prompt, the user can type in SQL commands. Ordinarily, input lines are sent to the server when a command-terminating **semicolon is reached**. An end of line does not terminate a command.

In other words, you have to end every statement with a `;`, in contrast to executing queries via a driver, which only requires `;` when you execute more than one query with a single request (you normally wouldn't do it).

Comment: @vitaly-t: your addition is only partly true. e.g. the JDBC driver _does_ allow sending multiple statements delimited with `;`